# Is it possible to run a react native app from the command line with default props as an arg?

Tags: react-native

I am integrating react native into an existing app. I am developing my react native page(s) separately as stand-alone apps.

In my existing legacy app, I call

`RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "AnAlert", initialProperties: someProperties)`

Where someProperties is a Dictionary of type `[String: Any]`, whose JSON representation may resemble something like:

`{"title": "Alert title", "body": "Alert body"}`

I would like to design my react native page independently of my main app, but the issue is that I require those initial properties to fully configure the page.

Does anyone know if it is possible to run `react-native run-ios <option>`, where `<option>` is an argument that is interpreted as default `props`?

When I ran `react-native run-ios --help`, I saw the additional options, but none of them seemed to describe what I want to do.

`-h, --help                output usage information
    --simulator [string]      Explicitly set simulator to use
    --configuration [string]  Explicitly set the scheme configuration to use
    --scheme [string]         Explicitly set Xcode scheme to use
    --project-path [string]   Path relative to project root where the Xcode project (.xcodeproj) lives. The default is 'ios'.
    --device [string]         Explicitly set device to use by name.  The value is not required if you have a single device connected.
    --udid [string]           Explicitly set device to use by udid
    --no-packager             Do not launch packager while building
    --config [string]         Path to the CLI configuration file`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I worked around this - I just edited my main index.ios.js file and put this at the top:

```
if (this.props == null) {
  var defaultProps = {"params": {"foo": "bar"}}
} else {
  var defaultProps = this.props
}
```

And then later in the file

```
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      {defaultProps.params.foo}
    </Text>
```

Now when I launch via the command line I get the defaults I embedded in the file, but when I launch via RCTRootView those debugging defaults are overridden.